# Google Blobstore add using curl POST

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, curl

I'm trying to use the code below to upload image to blobstore using curl and I get the following error "**Must be called from a blob upload callback request**".

However if I use a form with an action it does upload:

```
blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/upload")
```

===Servlet Code===

```
public class Upload extends HttpServlet {
private BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
    throws ServletException, IOException {

    Map<String, BlobKey> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploadedBlobs(req);
    BlobKey blobKey = blobs.get("myFile");

    }
```

}

Does anyone know how I can incorporate " blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/upload")" into the servlet so that I can perform curl requests as such:

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:8888/upload -F "myFile=@image.jpg"
```

I'm using the following example from Google's developer page:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way the Blobstore works:

1. You request a URL to do an upload (provision some resources).
2. The client uses that URL to post (this means, the request goes to the Blobstore servers and not your application).
3. The Blobstore servers receive the data, save it, and forward the request to your application.
4. You get the keys and run your code, then return to the client.

What I'm trying to say is that you must let the Blobstore do it's job, that means you can't have a fixed URL for uploads, you *must* first ask for a URL to post. This is how the system was designed.

So you'll have to make 2 `curl` calls, one to request the url, then use that to post, no other way around it.

Of course, it's not as sexy or simple, but other solutions would be complicated and even expensive.

Comment: Hi Jaime, do you know off how or any resources how to I make the first curl to request url?

Comment: Just add a handler that returns the result of `blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/upload")`.